# which approach is better for this purpose commandLink or outputLink or Link

Tags: jsf, primefaces

am working on an application and the designer drive me crazy. it's a jsf application with primefaces v.6 and apache tomcat v.7.

I have the following html code from designer

```
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a>
```

when the user click on it, he logout from the application.

When i use a `commandLink`

```
 <h:form>
    <p:commandLink action="#{loginBean.logout}" value="Logout"/>                            
</h:form>
```

it renders a form with hidden input-fields with an HTML anchor. therefore the link does not look like the one of my designer (CSS).

And when i use `outputLink` so that i can just have an anchor, it's not possible to call the bean method.

And it's also not possible to get this tag `<i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>` inside the anchor-element like it was designed.

I hope, i was a lil clear, how can i resolve this problem? To have a jsf-link-compenent or any other technic (jsf, primefaces) that can renders something like `<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a>`

I prefer the `commandLink` because of the capability to call a bean method

Any help will be welcome

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have never used the primefaces framework, but if I understood you correctly, the `p:commandLink` tag has a `styleClass` attribute which you can fill with your `fa fa-sign-out` classes.

http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/6.0/core/primefaces-p/commandLink.html

If that does not work, you could also put a `h:outputText` tag inside the `p:commandLink` and use the outputText `styleClass` attribute for the same effect.

Comment: i used the `styleClass` Attribut of `commandLink`, but i did not look like the link of the designer. i'll try the outputText. Thanks

Comment: do not work with `outputText` and `styleClass`attribute

Comment: i do it this way `<h:link outcome="/login.xhtml">
        <f:param name="logout" value="true"/>
        <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>
        #{msg['dashboard.toprow.logout']}
       </h:link>`